# Mysql Query Join two table Order by one table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two table (table 1 and table 2) . I want to show all the rows from table1 by joining with table2 which have multiple rows with same table1 id (foreign key relation) and will sort the result by table2 priority column (order by desc).

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Result will be

[image]

thanks in advance

Edit

```
Table1

id   name

1   test1 
2   test2
3   test5
4   test7
5   test9
6   test3


Table2


id  table1_id   event   priority

1   2             abc      0
2   2             kbc      0
3   2             abc      2
4   2             kbc      1
5   4             fgg      2
6   4             dss      3
7   1             fgfg     2
8   5             fgfg     2
9   6             xcxc     1
10  6             fgfh     3

Result

id_table1   name    event   priority

4   test7   dss     3
6   test3   fgfh    3
2   test2   abc     2
1   test1   fgfg    2
5   test9   fgfg    2
3   test5   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Is it just me or the image was not entered? Cant you just right down the schema?

Comment: sorry . R you unable to view the images ?

Comment: Yes but its probably just because of our firewall. Cant you type in the schema instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question you mentioned you need to select the data where id from `table1` is available more than once in the `table2` which does not match with the result set you gave.

Considering the original requirement the following should do the trick

```
select
t2.table1_id as id_table1,
t1.name,
t2.priority,
t2.event
from table1 t1
join
(
  select 
  p1.table1_id,
  p1.event,
  p2.priority
  from table2 p1
  join(
    select
    max(priority) as priority,
    table1_id
    from table2
    group by table1_id having count(*) > 1
  )p2
  on p2.table1_id = p1.table1_id and p2.priority = p1.priority

)t2
on t1.id = t2.t1id
order by t2.priority desc
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38344/1)

The result will get the same `event` corresponding the `max` `priority` column

Comment: YES. your query is right but I want to show all the results of table1. If foreign key is not available on table2 the row will show as NULL and I don't want ((having count(*) > 1)) as well.. thanks..

Comment: In that case you can do `from table1 t1
left join ( ... )` and remove the `having` clause.

Comment: Cool here is the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38344/4 you need to select the `t1.table1_id as id_table1` instead of `t2.table1_id as id_table1` if you want to show the id and name

Comment: Is there any way to optimize the query ? If I need only the name of table1 ?

Comment: yes you can select what ever you want on the outer query, but make sure inner query is selecting proper data since its used to join and grouping.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the result set that you want. You mentioned that you only need the items table1 ids that reflects more than once but result query shows tableid1 "1" even though it is only present once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,t1.name ,t2.event, t2.priority
FROM TABLE2 t2
right join 
TABLE1 t1
on t1.id=t2.table1_id
order by t2.priority desc
```

Comment: Sorry your query is not matching with my expected result set.. It's showing duplicate name on result set. Please check my result set.Order by priority wise your query is ok but only 6 rows will show..Need to add group by clause on your query...

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.priority FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
ORDER BY t2.priority DESC
```

Comment: As you can see the requirement displays values that are not present in table2. so using inner join isnt really the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Primary key and foreign key should have the same name. The syntax should be

```
SELECT Table1.id_table1,Table1.name,Table2.event,Table.priority FROM
Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON
Table1.id=Table2.id
ORDER BY Table2.priority DESC
```

Make the following changes in Table2:

1. Get rid of the first column or rename it
2. Rename second column(your foreign key) to "id".

Comment: As you can see the requirement displays values that are not present in table2. so using inner join isnt really the answer.